# Users cannot check in documents in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have a group settings applied with contribute but users cannot check in their own documents that they have uploaded. Any ideas on what the issue could be? Using Sharepoint 2013

Comment: did you check ULS log

Comment: What happens when they try to check in? Are they able to check out and in through the browser? Are they checking out and in using different approaches? What is the error/what happens when they try to check in?

Comment: Once they drop the file into the Library the user cannot check in the file or change any of the permissions. The (...) elipsies shows up, but the user cannot interact with it.

Comment: Thanks guys figured it out, IE was the isssue for the user

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer was on a previous version, once user switch to FF or Chrome issue was resolved instantly.